# MongoDB reIndex command not allowed in pymongo for atlasAdmin role

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I was testing the pymongo error messages for reaching my storage quota, and this resulted in me creating a 177.96MB index for a 4.03MB collection (after deleting the dummy logs used to fill my quota). I'm trying to delete the excess index, but I'm repeatedly receiving this error.

```
OperationFailure: CMD_NOT_ALLOWED: reIndex, full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'CMD_NOT_ALLOWED: reIndex', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

The MongoDB Role I'm using to access the cluster is atlasAdmin. So, I'm not sure why I wouldn't have access to this command. I'm getting the error when running the following lines.

```
client.database_name.collection_name.drop_indexes()
client.database_name.command({'reIndex': 'collection_name'})
```

Does anyone know why I would be unable to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Atlas free and shared clusters don't support all commands.  See https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/unsupported-commands/#unsupported-commands-in-m0-m2-m5-clusters

reIndex is on the list of unsupported commands.

You will either need to upgrade to an M10 or larger cluster, or drop and build each index separately.